# Are Super User rights required to update Joomla?

Tags: security, access

We are trying to lock down the SuperUser in our application, and only assign it to 2 people.  I have created a new group TIQAdmin that isn't a Super User, but has extensive rights in the back end. Trouble is, this user cannot apply Joomla! updates. Is it required to be a Super User to update Joomla?
Attached are two images of Global Configuration settings.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before Joomla 3.8.13, a non-super user could update core components. From 3.8.13, that is no longer possible.